# Rest API working from Developer Console but not from a Customer Portal site

Tags: rest-api, customer-portal, rest-service

I have a Force.com site where user logs in and can access service from a third party database. The data is retrieved using a REST API using OAuth. When I execute the REST call from Developer Console I am successfully (Status code 200) able to retrieve data. However when I am logged in as a Portal user it throw's a '401'error.

```
[
  {
    "code": "Unauthorized",
    "message": "You are not allowed to perform this action."
  }
]
```

Not sure what is the reason behind this behavior.

Portal user profile has access to all Site pages and controller.

Below is my code snippet for the callout

```
    Http h = new Http();
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setEndpoint(endpointURL);
    req.setMethod(method);
    req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + Access_Token__c);
    HttpResponse res = doCallout(h, req);
    return resp;
```

Comment: Where are you getting `Access_Token__c` from? If the other site is returning 401, then the token must be different between the two calls. Are you sure that record and field is accessible to the portal user?

Comment: @metadaddy Thanks for the response. Yes, I am getting access token from the other site. Third party system missed couple of configuration during this service setup. They fixed it on their part and now authentication is happening as expected.